# Map words in text to string in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure this can be done but I thought I would ask just in case. I have a recipe app, written in php. I want to convert the ingredients that are pasted into a text box and match it to a line in a mysql database. So for example, if if I had a table named ingredients and it contained

```
id       ingredient     calories
1        bread crumbs   10
2        egg            15
3        salt           1
```

and other table named recipes that contained

```
id    ingredient
```

Then the website had a text file to enter ingredients and you added:

```
1/2 cup bread crumbs
1 egg
1 tsp salt
```

I want to pull the "bread crumbs" out of the text, insert it into the `recipes` table, and match it to bread crumbs in the database, then take egg and salt and do the same thing. Then I could sum the calories for the recipe.

I'm basically trying to find the easiest way to extract the ingredients without having to enter it into individual fields or pull it from a drop down menu. The drop down menu would have hundreds of lines and be to difficult. This is obviously a very simplistic example and there are a lot of other things needed to be done but the extraction part is what I'm struggling to figure out. Any ideas?

Comment: Doing this well will be very difficult, because people make typos, they don't always enter data in the exact order you want, etc. You're much better off using menus with the ingredients, and a number input fields for the amount, etc.

Comment: If you have to ask here how to do it, you're not going to be able to do it well. It's not something that can be explained in a short answer, it's almost artificial intelligence to parse free-form text.

Comment: Yeah... I will be entering the text so I can make sure it matches, even only enter just the ingredient, just trying to find the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this to find the ingredient information from the database.

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT *
                FROM ingredients
                WHERE :input_string LIKE CONCAT('%', ingredient, '%')
                ORDER BY LENGTH(ingredient) DESC
                LIMIT 1");
$pdo->bindParam(':input_string', $_POST['ingredient']);
$pdo->execute();
```

`ORDER BY LENGTH` and `LIMIT 1` makes it return the longest match, so if they type `bread crumbs` it won't return `bread` or `rum` as well.

Parsing the quantity will be harder.

Comment: +1 for clever use of `CONCAT` to loosely compare to column header. What the OP is asking is tough though. Enforcing autocomplete on the front end and doing validation/reject if there is no exact match to expected values might be better.